# ignore g++ compile error for extra qualification for backwards compatibility 

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, g++

I am trying to port a project in a new Linux system with newer g++ version. While compiling I am getting the following:

> error: extra qualification 'Customer::' on member 'getCustomer'

Inside a class definition, I am prefixing getCustomer() with Customer::.

If I remove the ***Customer::*** my code works, however the code has a lot of entries prefixed  with class names and scope operator. Is there a way, eg a compiler directive, that helps eliminating this error?

From my shell **gcc version 4.4.2 20091027 (Red Hat 4.4.2-7) (GCC)**

Comment: This is an *error*, not a *warning*, so there must be something actually wrong with your code (which we cannot check btw). No flag can change that fact.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote and close request. This is part of production code on a - not that old - G++ system. Are we discussing programming issues here?

Comment: @bitmask, this was NOT an error in earlier versions and I asked if there is backwards compatibility in the compiler

Comment: I didn't down- or close-vote, but I assume somebody did because of the relative vagueness of the question that makes it hard to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @bitmask, my first comment was not for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inside a class definition, I am prefixing getCustomer() with Customer::.

I'm assuming you mean:

```
class Customer {
    Customer *Customer::getCustomer() { ... }
};
```

Don't. There's no need since you're already in the class definition, and I don't think the C++ standard even allows this (I'm surprised older G++ did?).

It seems there's no `-std` flag (in GCC 4.4.5) that permits this.

Comment: Yes your code is close to our code. Sorry for not posting this at the question. Do you mean that -std is needed?

Comment: No, I'm saying that `-std` doesn't seem to "fix" this, and that really, your code is broken.

Comment: G++ tightens up how closely it follows the standard with each version, so many things that are illegal used to be accepted.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: and I am personally thankful for that!

Answer (score 1):

**Such code can be compiled with `-fpermissive`.** (GCC 4.9.2, not clang 3.6.0)

I tested full program based on larsmans's interpretation:

```
#include <cstdio>
class Customer {
    public: Customer *Customer::getCustomer() { return this; }
};
int main()
{
    std:printf("%p\n", Customer().getCustomer());
}
```

It did not compile with `g++ test.cpp`, but it did compile (with a warning) with `g++ test.cpp -fpermissive`. Even `g++ test.cpp -fpermissive -ansi` and `g++ test.cpp -fpermissive -std=c++11` work.

With `-w` you do not get the warning, but maybe it is not always the best idea: you may want to get informed when something is strange.

`clang++ test.cpp -fpermissive` gives an error, although clang seems to recognize parameter `-fpermissive`. Maybe somebody knows a way to make it accept such code.